# Print all Constants of a python file

Tags: python, parsing, printing, module

I have a file config.py, which includes several constants.
How can I print all of them?
Something like:

```
for c in config:
    print c
```

This is of course not possible for a module config.py, as it's not iterable.

Comment: There is not really such a thing as constant in Python. There are only names, and they can be bound and re-bound to any value, and even deleted, during execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably `__dict__`.

```
for c in config.__dict__:
    print c
```

Would print all the names associated with `config`

```
for c in config.__dict__:
    print config.__dict__[c]
```

Would give you all values.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. As you said, it prints all names associated with config, including other imported files. But this can easily be handled

Comment: @user3453494 If this has answered your question, then you should accept it as the answer (Click the checkmark to the left)

Comment: note that the builtin `vars` is designed to do this without accessing 'magic' names

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Agreed, but according to [here](http://www.pythondoeswhat.com/2012/01/dict-and-vars.html) and elsewhere, the builtin `vars` is over 4.5x slower than using `__dict__`.